# AngularJS - ng-switch in directive ignoring numeric values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a set of repeated `ng-switch` statements that i am trying to create a directive for.

HTML:

```
<td ng-repeat="status in myStatus">
    <span ng-switch="status">
        <span ng-switch-when="0"></span>
        <span ng-switch-when="U">U</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="D">D</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="1">1</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="2">2</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="3">3</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="4">4</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="5">5</span>
        <span ng-switch-when="6">6</span>
        <span ng-switch-default></span>
    </span>
</td>
```

The above works fine when in my HTML, but when moved to a directive via:

```
<span history-status status-history='statusHistory'></span>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('historyStatus', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template:   '<span ng-switch="switchStatusHistory">' +
                    '<span ng-switch-when="U">U</span>' +
                    '<span ng-switch-when="D">D</span>' +
                    '<span ng-switch-when="1">1</span>' +
                    '<span ng-switch-when="2">2</span>' +
                    '<span ng-switch-when="3">3</span>' +
                    '<span ng-switch-when="4">4</span>' +
                    '<span ng-switch-when="5">5</span>' +
                    '<span ng-switch-when="6">6</span>' +                            
                    '<span ng-switch-when="null">null</span>' +
                    '<span ng-switch-default></span>' +
                '</span>',
    scope: {
        switchStatusHistory: '=statusHistory'
    }
};
```

});

Only the string values, so D and U are being outputted... The integers are being ignored.

My JSON looks as per:

```
["D", "1", "2", "U", "4", "1", "2", "A", "3", "D", "1", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Thanks

Comment: I would try it with `'<span ng-switch-when="\'1\'">U</span>'`. Maybe it's a type problem.

Comment: @Sulthan - that nearly worked.. The solution was to remove the ""... so: '<span ng-switch-when=\'1\'>U</span>'

Comment: Well, that is strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/9DWrEicfeSAnHYV3IaP0?p=preview

use "track by $index" because you have duplicate elments

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module("ng").directive('historyStatus', function () {
          return {
              restrict: 'A',
              replace: true,
              template:   '<span ng-switch on="switchStatusHistory">' +
                              '<span ng-switch-when="U">U</span>' +
                              '<span ng-switch-when="D">D</span>' +
                              '<span ng-switch-when="1">1</span>' +
                              '<span ng-switch-when="2">2</span>' +
                              '<span ng-switch-when="3">3</span>' +
                              '<span ng-switch-when="4">4</span>' +
                              '<span ng-switch-when="5">5</span>' +
                              '<span ng-switch-when="6">6</span>' +                            
                              '<span ng-switch-when="null">null</span>' +
                              '<span ng-switch-default></span>' +
                          '</span>',
              scope: {
                  switchStatusHistory: '=statusHistory'
              }
          };
        });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app>
    <div ng-init='myStatus=["D", "1", "2", "U", "4", "1", "2", "A", "3", "D", "1", "", "", "", "", "", ""]'></div>
    <div ng-repeat="status in myStatus track by $index">
      <span history-status status-history='status'></span>
    </div>

  </body>
```